# Insert SubString in a time input type

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, time, format

I have an time calculator which returns an input type of time in the following format: hh/mm/ss

It currently displays like this:

```
Let time = "03:00:00"
```

When I do a calculate function it return "3:0:0" instead and removes the "0".

How can I change this to be 03:00:00? The "0" must only be added if the h/m/s is less then 10.

Here are my calculate function if needed. The function returns the sum of time fron an array:

```
let testOne = ["02:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00"]

function test () {
let calTotalHours = testOne.map(t => t.split(':')).reduce((arr,item,index)=>{

    arr[0]+= parseFloat(item[0]);
    arr[1]+= parseFloat(item[1]);
    arr[2]+= parseFloat(item[2]);

    if(arr[2]>=60) {
        arr[1]++;
        arr[2]%=60;
    }
    if(arr[1]>=60) {
        arr[0]++;
        arr[1]%=60;
    }
    return arr;
},[0,0,0])
    .join(':')
    console.log(calTotalHours)
}
```

Comment: You already answered your question: *"if the h/m/s is less then 10."* Use an `if` statement to check if the value is less than 10 (or length < 2) and add the zero

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but not been able to solve it. When I add the 0 it does not let me return arr at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the zeros after the reduce, since reduce is still calculating the time.

I added a [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) after the calculation to get each value of time and then check if value is less than 10:

`.map((v) => (v < 10) ? v = "0" + v : v)`

```js
let testOne = ["02:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00"]

function test() {
  let calTotalHours = testOne.map(t => t.split(':')).reduce((arr, item, index) => {

    arr[0] += parseFloat(item[0]);
    arr[1] += parseFloat(item[1]);
    arr[2] += parseFloat(item[2]);

    if (arr[2] >= 60) {
      arr[1]++;
      arr[2] %= 60;
    }
    if (arr[1] >= 60) {
      arr[0]++;
      arr[1] %= 60;
    }

    return arr;
  }, [0, 0, 0]).map((v) => (v < 10) ? v = "0" + v : v).join(':')
  console.log(calTotalHours)
}

test()
```

Comment: Thank you man! Map was excatly what I was looking for! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to get what you want using `padStart()` function

```js
let testOne = ["02:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00"]

function test() {
  let calTotalHours = testOne.map(t => t.split(':')).reduce((arr, item, index) => {

      arr[0] += parseFloat(item[0]);
      arr[1] += parseFloat(item[1]);
      arr[2] += parseFloat(item[2]);

      if (arr[2] >= 60) {
        arr[1]++;
        arr[2] %= 60;
      }
      if (arr[1] >= 60) {
        arr[0]++;
        arr[1] %= 60;
      }


      return arr;
    }, [0, 0, 0])
    .map((num) => num.toString().padStart(2, 0)) //add 0 to each value here if they are less than 10
    .join(':');
  console.log(calTotalHours);

}
test();
```

Comment: the usage of `padStart` was nice here, got me +1

Comment: pasStart could do the job aswell! Thank you for the example. I've already marked Calvins answer as solved, but this works aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using .padStart() on before you join the array:

```
.map(num => num.toString().padStart(2, '0'))
```

This will fill out the leading 0's where the length is less than 2